# Can't use alias as field

Tags: mysql

Consider start of the query like this:

```
SELECT

(SELECT ps2.price FROM product_special ps2 
WHERE p.product_id = ps2.product_id 
AND ((ps2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_end > NOW()))
ORDER BY ps2.priority ASC, ps2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,

-- here is the problem, i can't use subquery alias special as field that i can
-- calculate with

IF(tr.rate ,CEILING(special + (special * tr.rate / 100 )),special) AS final_price

-- ending not important
```

Is there a way I can use alias as field in this query? I've already run through some of similar question on here, but none of them helped me.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in MySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known bug in MySQL in Sub Select queries, not possible to use for computation! You have a workaround in doing this way:

```
SELECT

(SELECT ps2.price FROM product_special ps2 
WHERE p.product_id = ps2.product_id 
AND ((ps2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_end > NOW()))
ORDER BY ps2.priority ASC, ps2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,
IF(tr.rate ,CEILING((SELECT ps2.price FROM product_special ps2 
WHERE p.product_id = ps2.product_id 
AND ((ps2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_end > NOW()))
ORDER BY ps2.priority ASC, ps2.price ASC LIMIT 1)+ ((SELECT ps2.price FROM product_special ps2 
WHERE p.product_id = ps2.product_id 
AND ((ps2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_end > NOW()))
ORDER BY ps2.priority ASC, ps2.price ASC LIMIT 1)* tr.rate / 100 )),(SELECT ps2.price FROM product_special ps2 
WHERE p.product_id = ps2.product_id 
AND ((ps2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps2.date_end > NOW()))
ORDER BY ps2.priority ASC, ps2.price ASC LIMIT 1)) AS final_price
```

I know this might be crazy but check if it works!

Comment: This offcourse works for me. It's just that its confusing, not readable and i was thinking if this query is not much slower than it would be, if i can use alias.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I tackle the issue! :( I too had the same issue. Nothing I could do about it. Not even views worked!